# Ensuring that a resizing keeps the border to width/height ratio constant

Tags: inkscape

In a document I want to create some symbols which ratio of contour over width/height are kept constant when I resize. See the picture below to understand what is the issue:

Big size:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

As you see, when I "shrink" the image, it gets "more boldy", meaning that the contour are wider in ratio to the height/width.

How can I fix this issue? The units of my document are in px.

[Here is a link](https://easyupload.io/04w9xt) to download the .svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep this button pressed. On the top pannel, the first button.

[image]

When you hover them you can read a tooltip with the function of each.